# Find number missing in file

Tags: bash, perl, unix, awk

I have a file with definitions similar to this one:

```
some code
some more code
var 1=foo
var 2=bar // next line is missing
var 4=one // continuing with 4
var 5=or
var 6=multiple
var 7=lines
var 8=are
var 9=missing
var 10=!
bla
```

I am trying to find the line I accidentally deleted. Unfortunately my file is not 10 lines big, but rather 10000 lines.

I had the idea of grepping for every single number and echoing the number out when there was no result, but since my single digit numbers don't have a "0" as prefix, it will find the 10 and so on.

I would prefer a bash / awk / perl or vim solution.

Comment: And... what have you tried? StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service where you publish requirements and someone builds a solution.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have added one of the things I have thought of in the question. 
I am pretty lost here, else I wouldn't ask. This is something I can't accomplish and I need it for a non-profit project.

Comment: I understand - it's important for you. But it doesn't matter that it's for a non-profit project - you're posting, asking someone to write something for you. This is not for StackOverflow.

Comment: You are probably right and I won't argue with you about how fitting my question is. I needed help with programming and the first place I think about is StackOverflow, so I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted sample input and what you've tried so far (grep for individual numbers), all you're really missing from your question is the expected output so start with this and massage to suit:

```
$ awk -F'[ =]' -v OFS=':' '$1!="var"{next} $2!=(p+1){print NR, $0} {p=$2}' file
5:var 4=one // continuing with 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
awk magic I don't understand of course.. But it works!

Comment: The example input is sorted. When the real input is not sorted, `sort -n` before using the `awk`.